# Bootstrap popover fade after click

Tags: jquery

Im trying to get popover to show when user clicks button. However when i use fade the element gets removed and not the popup.

```
<button id="cartbtn" class="btn btn-danger btn-small">Add to Cart</button>

$('#cartbtn').popover({
    placement:'top', 
    trigger:'manual', 
    html:true, 
    content:'Added!', 
    delay: { 
        show:500, 
        hide:100 
    } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m42rcqry/

Comment: Do you by chance also have Prototype loaded on your site?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add timeout function and destroy popup

```
function ex(){       
$('#cartbtn').popover('destroy');
}   

$("#cartbtn").click(function(){           

    $('#cartbtn').popover({ placement:'top', trigger:'manual', html:true, content:'Added!' }).popover('show');

    setTimeout(ex,1000);

});
```